# Installing Profile2 on Commerce Kickstart

Tags: commerce, users

When installing the module: "Profile2" to distribution of Drupal 7: "Commerce Kickstart".
and, I do activate, but got the following error:

---

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache Server at mydomain.com Port 80

---

And since then, every page or link that I want to enter it shows me the same error message.
I deleted the file. Htaccess (I think it has to do something this file) but still the same error persists.

Please someone can provide some possible solution?

Best Regards

Comment: check your database log for errors and paste it here so we can get much proper idea of what is going on

Comment: I do not know how to do to get that error log in the mysql, excuse my ignorance. is that I am still a learner.

Seems to have been a server issue. now suddenly I do not get that message, and that I have not done anything. I'm on Godaddy, idk if you better switch to another?

thanks

Comment: Well its always a good idea to switch from Godaddy not because of this error, but still if you still can visit your admin in drupal, go ahead and eanble message log module, then under report section look for error logs, and if you can't take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039799/where-can-i-find-mysql-logs-in-phpmyadmin